# Quintic Polynomial

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I have a polynomial of degree five as ($x > 0$)

$y = A x^5 + B x^4 + C x^3 + D x^2 + E x$,

where $A$ is positive.

I would like to find some sufficient conditions (inequalities) on coefficients  in order $y$ becomes negative for some values of $x$. It can be done for example in this way:

In general, a quintic function function looks like as

[image: Here]

In order in some way it becomes negative, one can force the derivative of the function to have four real roots (which in principle there are some conditions in order a four degree polynomial has four real roots), then, to demand the value of $y$ at its rightmost minimum becomes negative. So we obtain some inequalities on coefficients, which leads to a negative $y$ near its rightmost minimum.

However, it's somewhat clumsy and cumbersome. Can you think of something simpler?

**Example for some illustration**:

If we have ($x > 0$)

$y = A x^2 + B x + c$,

where $A > 0$.

One possible way that $y$ can become negative:

One can obtain the minimum of this function, and force $y$ becomes negative at its minimum. So we can obtain some conditions on coefficients in order $y$ becomes negative (for $x$'s near the minimum). This is indeed one possible way to have negative $y$ for some values of $x$.

Comment: But if $A \neq 0$, there will be always some $x$ such that $y(x)<0$.

Comment: Are you asking whether y<0 for some x, or are you looking for negative values of y within some limited range of x? The first is easy.

Comment: @mrprottolo Yes, I want to obtain some conditions for one possible situation.

Comment: Like the others hint, $\lim_{x \to -\infty} y(x) = -\infty$, so there is $y$ is always negative for some values of $x$. Do you mean, for example, conditions on the coefficients such that there is some $a$ larger than the smallest root of $y$ such that $y(a) < 0$*, i.e., that $y$ is negative on two intervals and nonnegative between those two interval?

Comment: @user254665 For example if I force the function to behave as above, I am certainly sure that near global minimum it's negative.

Comment: ...or (nearly equivalently, modulo some cases involving double roots) that $y$ has more than one real root?

Comment: @Travis Oh sorry, $x$ is positive.

Comment: @David The functions $y$ as defined are unbounded below, so they have no global minimum.

Comment: @Travis By global minimum, I mean the farthest minimum at the right of the above figure.

Comment: @Travis I have considered the middle extremums as local, and the others as global.

Comment: *Global* has a preexisting (and very different) meaning in this context. One ought to say something like "the rightmost minimum".

Comment: I'm still unclear on what you're asking. Is it, "What are sufficient conditions such that the rightmost minimum of $y(x)$ is negative?" (...but then, this doesn't involve positivity of $x$...)

Comment: @Travis I have added an example to the post.

Comment: Hmm, in the cubic case to have a negative rightmost minimum it's enough to have three roots (and at least two distinct roots), so one can just ask for the discriminant to be nonnegative (and have that the cubic is not of the form $A(x - S)^3$), but this does not itself tell you the sign of the $x$-value of the minimum. It's not hard to produce an easy condition on the coefficients to determine it, but this uses the explicit form of the quadratic formula, so this is difficult to generalize to the quintic case.

Answer (score 2):

With $A>0$ : For $x\ne 0$ we have $$y=A x^5(1+(1/A )(B/ x+C/x^2+D/x^3+E/x^4)).$$ So if $$|x|>W=\max (1,|B|/8,|C|/8,|D|/8,|E|/8)$$ then $$y=A x^5 (1+z) \quad \text {where } |z|<1/2.$$ So $x>W\implies y>Ax^5/2$ and $x<-W\implies y<-A|x|^5/2.$  Therefore the range of $y$ is unbounded above and unbounded below.Since $y$ is a continuous function of $x$, its range therefore is all of $R$.

Comment: Do you mean that $y$ can become negative, for some negative $x$? But in my question $x$ is positive.